# Groupby one column, filter the most recent N periods of the actual values, and the nearest M periods of the predicted values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

This is a mini version of the result of my time series prediction of multiple indicators. For the sub-dataset corresponding to each `indicator_name`, I hope to take the last 3 periods for the `actual_value` part (`fitted_value` is a fit to the `actual_value`, so they are of equal length), and the next 2 periods for the `predicted_value` part. How to achieve this?

```
   indicator_name        date  actual_value  fitted_value  predicted_value
0             CPI  2023-07-31          -7.7     -9.280851              NaN
1             CPI  2023-08-31          72.5      5.181248              NaN
2             CPI  2023-09-30         126.3     75.801026              NaN
3             CPI  2023-10-31         147.9    123.940712              NaN
4             CPI  2023-11-30           NaN           NaN       113.341466
5             CPI  2023-12-31           NaN           NaN       103.223588
6             CPI  2024-01-31           NaN           NaN       117.865400
7             PPI  2022-09-30          25.8     12.700000              NaN
8             PPI  2022-12-31           6.0     12.800000              NaN
9             PPI  2023-03-31           6.1      8.800000              NaN
10            PPI  2023-06-30           7.9      9.700000              NaN
11            PPI  2023-09-30           8.1     11.000000              NaN
12            PPI  2023-12-31           NaN           NaN        11.500000
13            PPI  2024-03-31           NaN           NaN        13.700000
14            PPI  2024-06-30           NaN           NaN        12.800000
15            PPI  2024-09-30           NaN           NaN        15.300000
```

The expected results are as follows:

```
  indicator_name        date  actual_value  fitted_value  predicted_value
0            CPI  2023-08-31          72.5      5.181248              NaN
1            CPI  2023-09-30         126.3     75.801026              NaN
2            CPI  2023-10-31         147.9    123.940712              NaN
3            CPI  2023-11-30           NaN           NaN       113.341466
4            CPI  2023-12-31           NaN           NaN       103.223588
5            PPI  2023-03-31           6.1      8.800000              NaN
6            PPI  2023-06-30           7.9      9.700000              NaN
7            PPI  2023-09-30           8.1     11.000000              NaN
8            PPI  2023-12-31           NaN           NaN        11.500000
9            PPI  2024-03-31           NaN           NaN        13.700000
```

Code:

```
def slice_act_dataframe(df, by_cols, n: int=3):
    df = df.sort_values('date')
    df_sliced = df.groupby(by_cols).tail(n)
    return df_sliced

def slice_pred_dataframe(df, by_cols, n: int=2):
    df = df.sort_values('date')
    df_sliced = df.groupby(by_cols).head(n)
    return df_sliced
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
def slice_dataframe(df, by_cols, n_act: int = 3, n_pred: int = 2):
    df = df.sort_values('date')
    # Slice actual values
    df_act = df[df['actual_value'].notna()]
    df_act_sliced = df_act.groupby(by_cols).tail(n_act)
    # Slice predicted values
    df_pred = df[df['predicted_value'].notna()]
    df_pred_sliced = df_pred.groupby(by_cols).head(n_pred)
    # Concatenate sliced dataframes
    df_sliced = pd.concat([df_act_sliced, df_pred_sliced])
    return df_sliced
df_sliced = slice_dataframe(df, by_cols=['indicator_name']).sort_values(['indicator_name', 'date'])
print(df_sliced)
```

Out:

```
  indicator_name        date  actual_value  fitted_value  predicted_value
1             CPI  2023-08-31          72.5      5.181248              NaN
2             CPI  2023-09-30         126.3     75.801026              NaN
3             CPI  2023-10-31         147.9    123.940712              NaN
4             CPI  2023-11-30           NaN           NaN       113.341466
5             CPI  2023-12-31           NaN           NaN       103.223588
9             PPI  2023-03-31           6.1      8.800000              NaN
10            PPI  2023-06-30           7.9      9.700000              NaN
11            PPI  2023-09-30           8.1     11.000000              NaN
12            PPI  2023-12-31           NaN           NaN        11.500000
13            PPI  2024-03-31           NaN           NaN        13.700000
```

Comment: It's probably more efficient to get rid of `by_cols` and the `groupby`s in `slice_dataframe` and do the `groupby` once externally i.e. `df.groupby('indicator_name').apply(slice_dataframe)`. Other than that no obvious improvements come to mind.